# why has_one association with nested routes gives access to all possible routes in the url search bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-one

I am confused with the way you can get every url such as deals/:id/properties/:id despite having a one-to-one association btw a deal and a property. How come is that possible that I can type and get deals/2/properties/14 (or any combination) in the browser url when the property associated with deal 2 is property 6 in my database. The links I have in the views do work and I get the right association deals/2/properties/6 using the links but my question is there something I did wrong in the setup (or everywhere else) or is that just Rails allowing every possible combination to be tested in the browser.... If yes is there a way to prevent this to happen? Thanks a lot

I have a one-to-one association => 1 deal has_one property and a property belongs_to deal. I have nested routes as follows

```
    resources :deals, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
      scope '/siteadmin' do
        resources :properties
      end
    end

    scope '/siteadmin' do
      resources :deals, except: [:index, :show]
    end
```

deal.rb

```
    class Deal < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :property, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :property
    end
```

property.rb

```
    class Property < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :deal
      validates :full_address, presence: true
      validates_uniqueness_of :deal_id
    end
```

deals_controller.rb

```
      class DealsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_deal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      def index
        @deals = Deal.all
      end
      def show
        @property = @deal.property
      end
      def new
        @deal = Deal.new
      end
      def create
        @deal = Deal.new(deal_params)
        if @deal.save
          redirect_to deals_path, notice: 'Deal was successfully created'
        else
        render :new
        end
      end
      def edit
      end
      def update
        if @deal.update(deal_params)
          redirect_to @deal, notice: 'Deal was successfully updated'
        else
          flash.now[:alert] = "Deal has not been updated."
          render :edit
        end
      end
      def destroy
        @deal.destroy
        redirect_to deals_path, notice: 'Deal was successfully deleted'
      end

      private
      def deal_params
        params.require(:deal).permit(:description, :kind, :address, :image_url, :occupancy, :yield)
      end
      def set_deal
        @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        flash[:alert] = "The deal you were looking for could not be found."
        redirect_to deals_path
      end
    end
```

properties_controller.rb

```
    class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_deal
    before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @properties = Property.all.order(id: :asc)
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
      @property = @deal.build_property
    end
    def create
      @property = @deal.build_property(property_params)
      if @property.save
        flash[:notice] = "Property has been created."
        redirect_to [@deal, @property]
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Property has not been created."
        render "new"
      end
    end
    def edit
    end

    def update
      if @property.update(property_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Property has been updated."
        redirect_to [@deal, @property]
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Property has not been updated."
        render "edit"
      end
    end
    def destroy
      @property.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Property has been deleted."
      redirect_to @deal
    end
    private
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:genre, :surface, :nb_rooms, :nb_bedrooms, :city, :district, :full_address)
    end
    def set_property
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    end
    def set_deal
      @deal = Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
    end
  end
```

deals show.html.erb

```
<h2>Property in the deal:</h2>
<ul class="list-unstyled text-justify">
  <li>Property id #<%= @deal.property.try(:id) %> - <%= link_to @deal.property.try(:full_address), [@deal, @property] %></li>
  <li>Adresse of the property: <%= @deal.property.try(:full_address) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "see all the properties", deal_properties_path(@deal) %></li>
  <%= link_to "add deal", new_deal_path, {class: "btn btn-primary"} %>
</ul>
```

properties index.html.erb

```
      <header>
      <h2>All properties</h2>
      <ul id="properties in the db">
      <% @properties.each do |property| %>
      <li>Property id #<%= property.id %> - <%= link_to property.full_address, deal_property_path(property.deal, property) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "See our Deal", deal_path(property.deal) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Edit Property", edit_deal_property_path(property.deal, property) %></li>
      <li>Deal id #<%= property.deal.id %></li>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      </ul>
      <ul class="actions">
        <li><%= link_to "Add Property", new_deal_property_path(@deal),
          class: "new" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Back to deals", deals_path%></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

properties show.html.erb

```
   <header>
   <h2>Property id #<%= @property.id %> <%= @property.full_address %></h2>
   </header>
   <h3>This is the property #<%= @property.id %> of the Deal @<%= @deal.id %> - <%= @deal.address %></h3>
   <p>This property is located at <%= @property.full_address %></p>
   <li><%= link_to "See all the properties", deal_properties_path(@deal)%></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the routes handles just the format of the query string not the values in it.

what I like to do is scope the data in the controller like this

```
    class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_deal
    before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @properties = Property.all.order(id: :asc)
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
      @property = @deal.build_property
    end
    def create
      @property = @deal.build_property(property_params)
      if @property.save
        flash[:notice] = "Property has been created."
        redirect_to [@deal, @property]
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Property has not been created."
        render "new"
      end
    end
    def edit
    end

    def update
      if @property.update(property_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Property has been updated."
        redirect_to [@deal, @property]
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Property has not been updated."
        render "edit"
      end
    end
    def destroy
      @property.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Property has been deleted."
      redirect_to @deal
    end
    private
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:genre, :surface, :nb_rooms, :nb_bedrooms, :city, :district, :full_address)
    end
    def set_property
      @property = @deal.property #.find(params[:id]) # you don't need to find it because there is only 1
    end
    def set_deal
      @deal = Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you Jose I can now see that whatever the url I try to type it will always show the right deal-property combination whatever the url. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help

Comment: You are doing amazing :) I hope that you keep asking questions and submitting answers :) I am also new at this I just have 28 points my self